# What does "Rabid, rabid" mean

Tags: word-meaning

What does "Rabid, rabid" mean in this image?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: I don't know what the source for that is, but it is terrible English.  Did the princess really mean "Become a prince.  You arouse me sexually. I don't find you sexually arousing.  Become a frog."

Comment: @JamesK Not to be rude to the author, but I don't think the cartoon is very interesting or funny. I'm not sure if "you turn me on" here means "I find you sexually arousing" or ... what.

Comment: @JamesK Given that it appears to be a children's cartoon, I'd be inclined to give it the benefit of the doubt and assume that "you turn me off" isn't using the sexual meaning of that phrase (e.g. to provoke disinterest), but I don't think "turn me on" can be used that way.

Comment: Since this is ELL, just for what it's worth, I suggest *not* using whatever source that came from to learn English. The English above is...not good (not least because of the "rabid" thing, which **no** competent English speaker would use as the noise for a frog).

Comment: I suspect there's a (poor) pun at work here.

Comment: @nick012000 "You turned me on" means "you aroused me sexually".  It might have other meanings, but that is the main one.   I agree it looks as if it is made for children.  This is why I say it is "terrible English".  You should not be teaching children to say "you turned me on" because this is a sexual expression.

Comment: Judging by the appearance of the text, the strong contrast, the sharp lines but the blurry fuzzy image, it suggests that the text was a recent addition. I am tempted to say that whoever wrote those lines or translated the original  were pulling our leg or failed to refer back to the original.

Comment: By the way, it should be the **frog** who's saying: "You **turned me back into** a prince"

Comment: This isn't supposed to be a humorous cartoon, it's some sort of educational material with badly translated captions stuck on it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

"Rabid, rabid" here is just imitating the noise that a frog makes. Like we say "The dog says 'woof'" or "The cat says 'meow'". The fact that "rabid" is a word referring to an animal disease is just a coincidence.

I think it's more common for English speakers to say that a frog says "ribbit" or "ribbid", but in this context I don't see any significance to the non-standard attempt to spell out the sound.

Comment: I think it's an unfortunate choice of a word to represent a frog's sound. "Rabid" also metaphorically means "raging insanely".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Yes. I'm not sure if there was intended to be a double meaning there or if it was just a poor choice of a word.

Comment: I suspect the nonstandard spelling is because the translation was not done by a fluent English speaker. The rest of the wording also is unnatural.

Comment: I agree with others that while this answer seems to have correctly guessed at the intended meaning of the phrase, "rabid, rabid" is not what frogs say in English; they say "ribbit" or make a croaking noise. This answer is being a little too kind to the source in question.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Frogs do not say, "Rabid, Rabid."  No.  Cats do not say, "Puke, Puke" and dogs do not say "Ouch, Ouch".  Best to choose a sound that does not already stand for some other negative event or action.  Maybe a See & Say?

Comment: The sound represented by "rabid" and "the disease" are not coincidental, the supposedly onomatopoeic word is clearly an error.

Comment: Another possible explanation - the first thing I thought of when I looked at the captions was that it's the kind of error you see from computerised voice-recognition, like subtitles on a TV programme.  Perhaps the computer heard the frog noise and that was the closest thing among the words it had in its dictionary.  That doesn't explain "you turn me on" and "you turn me off", though.  What IS this game/cartoon?  Is it in fact a parody of some kind, mimicking a children's cartoon but meant for adults?

Comment: @A.B. Now that you mention it, maybe not voice recognition software, but a human being hearing the words trying to match them to a word he knows or looks up. Like I'm reminded of a person I once knew for whom English was not his first language who was invited to a "birthday party" and told me that he had been invited to a "bird party". I can see that being doubly a problem if the word he hears is not a real word, just a nonsense sound or animal noise -- like "ribbid" -- and he's trying to match it to a real word.

Answer (score 17):

**"Rabid" is not what frogs say in idiomatic English**

As other answers have indicated, the source in question appears to be trying to represent the sound a frog makes. It made several mistakes unfortunately, and don't seem to be a good source for learning English. While "rabid" is understandable in context (if somewhat jarring), using it out of context would be downright confusing, since "rabid" means "having rabies".

**The idiomatic spelling is "ribbit"**

It is the conventional and idiomatic way to spell the sound in question in English.

**Find another ESL resource**

The resource in question tries hard, but is not a good representation of English. There are many non-idiomatic phrases, and the phrases "turn on" and "turn off" as used imply sexual arousal, something not appropriate in a children's book, indicating the possibility that the text was translated incorrectly from another language. A better resource is Woodward English (I'm not affiliated with them in any way, but  have used their materials in my own ESL classes): https://www.woodwardenglish.com/

Comment: -1 To say that the conventional form is "correct" and other forms are incorrect is to trat this as far more rule-based than actual English usage is, and is itself incorrect. One can say that a given term is "standard" or "conventional" or on the other hand is "non-standard." but that does not make it "incorrect". It may or may not be confusing in a given context.

Comment: I'm using "correct" and "incorrect" as short-hand to indicate the likelihood of being understand/accepted as speaking correctly in conversational English. In that context, e.g. "ain't" would be correct, while "amn't" would not, since people use the former but not the latter. Likewise in conversation "ribbit" is "correct" since it is commonly used (when making frog sounds would be appropriate :)), and "rabid" is "incorrect" since it's not commonly used in speech. Just to clarify.

Comment: I think you will find on this site "incorrect" is generally used to mean "violating a widely accepted rule of usage or grammar" and other terms such as "not idiomatic", "not natural", "uncommon", "non-standard", "awkward"  "unusual"", and "unclear" are used to indicate that something would not often be said or written by native or fluent speakers.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Ok. I'm fine with changing my terms to go with the crowd. Thanks for the info--I'm new to this group.

Comment: Updated to use "idiomatic"

Comment: Thank you. Many learners here take "wrong" and 'incorrect" very strongly. And many assume tht English is far more rule-based than it is in practice, a problem which many texts contribute to.

Comment: I understand. :)

Answer (score 14):

"Rabid Rabid" here is intended to represent the croaking noise that a frog makes. It is more often represented as "Ribbit, Ribbit." As with other traditional representations of animal sounds, like "Moo" for a cow, "Meow" for a cat, "Caw" for a crow, and so on, it is at best a rough approximation to the actual sound.

Comment: "Ribbit" has apparently come to be the conventional way of representing a frog's croak because the frogs found near Hollywood make a sound like that, even though very few other species of frog do!

Comment: @Kate Bunting That is very interesting. Is there a source for it?

Comment: I read it long ago, but through googling 'Ribbit' I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baja_California_chorus_frog)

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you.

Comment: I found curious that in English the verb is to croak but the onomatopeia is not "croak"... while it is in Spanish, for example.

Comment: @KateBunting are you sure you read it some time ago? I know it was featured on QI so you may have watched that. That said it is well researched so there is probably a well referenced source for their claim.

Comment: Yes, I may have heard it on QI. @user126545 The verb 'croak' (which _does_ sound more like the sound made by European frogs) is much older than 'ribbit', which originated with Hollywood films.

Comment: To strengthen this answer a bit, "rabid" is not a valid noise to use for a frog in English. If you say "rabid, rabid" out of context, people will have no idea what you're saying, and may look around for a rabid dog. If you say "ribbit, ribbit", they'll wonder why you're making a frog noise. :)

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: @bob I wouldn't say that "rabid" is not a "valid" noise. That assumes that there is a single valid form, and others are not. It is not the standard or stereotypical way to represent the frog noise, and if used without context may be confusing, particularly since it is an actual word. If one says "Raddit, raddit" this confusion would not be as likely. When the context makes it clear that a particular noise is intended, non-standard ways of spelling or pronouncing it are not uncomm0on, and will be understood and accepted.

Comment: I guess it would depend. If the source is clearly intending to be whimsical and different, it could be ok. But if somebody used "rabid, rabid" in conversation (not sure why they would), it would be...weird. It's just not what probably 99+% of the native English speaking population associates with a frog sound (at least in the U.S., from my experience). So in that sense it's wrong, though there are always exceptions (e.g. in poetry).

Comment: @bob, it is not uncommon foe someone to attempt to more accurately represent an animal sound than the "standard" terrm for it, which is often not very accurate. (For example "meow" does not well represent any of the sounds a cat makes. I have seen "Mewr" written for this purpose,) This may be more common in writing than speech. But context is vital in such cases, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I don't disagree. But it would be odd to use such a spelling in ESL materials, or as you say in conversation. I'm coming from the latter perspective, hence my leaning towards saying it's "wrong" here. But I agree that in writing there is more variability possible.

Comment: @Bob I will agree that such a non-standard use would be unusual in content aimed specifically at an ESL audience. But learners will encounter much content not so designed and aimed. People often feel free to modify the standard sounds, both in conversation and even more in writing, and a learner must be able to grasp that ]such uses occur and how they are intended.

Answer (score -1):

Rabid(or Ribbit) means that the frog croaks (which is basically the sound that the frogs make).

Comment: The sound that _some_ frogs make - see the discussion under David's answer.

Comment: Okay.....I have never a seen frog in my life (maybe in zoo but never paid attention to them)so I don't have any idea about what kind of sound they make here in India :)